# How to Fix: android/arcgis unfortunately <app> has stopped

Tags: android-studio, mapping, android-mapview, arcgis

I am a newbie to combining ArcGIS with Android.  I am attempting to execute one of the ArcGIS example mapping programs.  It is a simple Map Display program.  It executes successfully using a Nexus6 emulator On Android 6.0.1 (Marshmallow) using Android Studio 2.1.2.  When I port it to the actual device, a SAMSUNG-SM-G920V Galaxy s6, it fails immediately with the message: “Unfortunately  has stopped.  This happens immediately when I press its icon on the phone.
I have successfully executed other Android non-ArcGIS mapping applications on this same phone without any issues.  These were all developed using Android Studio, not Eclipse.

I have registered the application with ESRI Developer Licensing and provided the ‘Client_ID” in my code.

I have spent hours combing through Google trying various suggestions without any success.

Here is my main Activity:

```
package com.example.scott.myfirstmap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.esri.android.runtime.ArcGISRuntime;
import com.esri.core.runtime.LicenseResult;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ArcGISRuntime.setClientId("q9Xjd7ApZFBdf9DP");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LicenseResult licR = ArcGISRuntime.setClientId(getString(R.string.ArcGISClientId));
        Log.e("NOHE",licR.toString());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Here is the Main Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.scott.myfirstmap.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <!-- MapView -->
    <com.esri.android.map.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        mapoptions.MapType="Topo"
        mapoptions.center="41.460510, -82.702001"
        mapoptions.ZoomLevel="16">
    </com.esri.android.map.MapView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.scott.myfirstmap">

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the Project build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        // Add the following ArcGIS repository
        maven {
            url 'https://esri.bintray.com/arcgis'
        }
    }
    dependencies {// Add ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android dependency
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        // Add the following ArcGIS repository
        maven {
            url 'https://esri.bintray.com/arcgis'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is my Application build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp/pom.xml'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.scott.myfirstmap"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Add ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android dependency
    compile 'com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.8'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
}
```

Here is the Logcat from the phone:

```
--------- beginning of main
W/SELinux (11028): SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=org.jtb.alogcat 
D/TimaKeyStoreProvider(11028): TimaSignature is unavailable
D/ActivityThread(11028): Added TimaKeyStore provider
I/InjectionManager(11028): Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
--------- beginning of system
W/ResourcesManager(11028): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/org.jtb.alogcat-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in org.jtb.alogcat rsrc of package org.jtb.alogcat
D/ResourcesManager(11028): For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
I/InjectionManager(11028): Inside getClassLibPath caller 
W/System  (11028): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/org.jtb.alogcat-1/lib/arm64
D/InjectionManager(11028): InjectionManager
D/InjectionManager(11028): fillFeatureStoreMap org.jtb.alogcat
I/InjectionManager(11028): Constructor org.jtb.alogcat, Feature store :{}
I/InjectionManager(11028): featureStore :{}
W/ResourcesManager(11028): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/org.jtb.alogcat-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in org.jtb.alogcat rsrc of package org.jtb.alogcat
W/ResourcesManager(11028): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/org.jtb.alogcat-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in org.jtb.alogcat rsrc of package org.jtb.alogcat
D/AbsListView(11028): Get MotionRecognitionManager
E/MotionRecognitionManager(11028): mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@32be3e3
E/MotionRecognitionManager(11028): motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@db161e0
E/MotionRecognitionManager(11028): motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@db161e0
D/Activity(11028): performCreate Call Injection manager
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : org.jtb.alogcat.LogActivity isFragment :false
D/SecWifiDisplayUtil(11028): Metadata value : SecSettings2
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{ad8c5d1 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #1 mView = android.widget.LinearLayout{b381836 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :org.jtb.alogcat.LogActivity
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :org.jtb.alogcat.LogActivity
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
I/Timeline(11028): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@da97a14 time:83570460
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #3 mView = null
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :org.jtb.alogcat.LogActivity
D/AbsListView(11028): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #1 mView = android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView{10cdb79 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchOptionsItemSelected :org.jtb.alogcat.LogActivity
I/Timeline(11028): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:org.jtb.alogcat time:83576932
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #3 mView = null
E/ViewRootImpl(11028): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
W/ResourcesManager(11028): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/org.jtb.alogcat-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in org.jtb.alogcat rsrc of package org.jtb.alogcat
W/ResourcesManager(11028): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/org.jtb.alogcat-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in org.jtb.alogcat rsrc of package org.jtb.alogcat
D/AbsListView(11028): Get MotionRecognitionManager
E/MotionRecognitionManager(11028): mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@dea48df
E/MotionRecognitionManager(11028): motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@a6f292c
E/MotionRecognitionManager(11028): motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@a6f292c
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchBuildHeader > Target : org.jtb.alogcat.PrefsActivity
D/AbsListView(11028): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/Activity(11028): performCreate Call Injection manager
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchPreferences > Target : org.jtb.alogcat.PrefsActivity
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : org.jtb.alogcat.PrefsActivity isFragment :false
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{94b71c4 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
D/SecWifiDisplayUtil(11028): Metadata value : SecSettings2
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :org.jtb.alogcat.PrefsActivity
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :org.jtb.alogcat.PrefsActivity
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
I/Timeline(11028): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@667c671 time:83577129
V/ActivityThread(11028): updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{136c71d token=android.os.BinderProxy@da97a14 {org.jtb.alogcat/org.jtb.alogcat.LogActivity}} show : false
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/AbsListView(11028): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{f4ead8c V.E...... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #3 mView = null
E/ViewRootImpl(11028): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processKey 0
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processKey 1
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #1 mView = android.widget.LinearLayout{6cfd989 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
I/Timeline(11028): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@da97a14 time:83589169
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #3 mView = null
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #3 mView = null
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :org.jtb.alogcat.LogActivity
D/AbsListView(11028): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #1 mView = android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView{a10da8 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchOptionsItemSelected :org.jtb.alogcat.LogActivity
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #3 mView = null
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #1 mView = android.widget.LinearLayout{ec97cf2 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
E/ViewRootImpl(11028): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #3 mView = null
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :org.jtb.alogcat.LogActivity
D/AbsListView(11028): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #1 mView = android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView{6e763e V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchOptionsItemSelected :org.jtb.alogcat.LogActivity
I/Timeline(11028): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:org.jtb.alogcat time:83681223
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #3 mView = null
E/ViewRootImpl(11028): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
W/ResourcesManager(11028): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/org.jtb.alogcat-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in org.jtb.alogcat rsrc of package org.jtb.alogcat
D/AbsListView(11028): Get MotionRecognitionManager
E/MotionRecognitionManager(11028): mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@35706a2
E/MotionRecognitionManager(11028): motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@35f5f33
E/MotionRecognitionManager(11028): motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@35f5f33
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchBuildHeader > Target : org.jtb.alogcat.PrefsActivity
D/AbsListView(11028): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/Activity(11028): performCreate Call Injection manager
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchPreferences > Target : org.jtb.alogcat.PrefsActivity
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : org.jtb.alogcat.PrefsActivity isFragment :false
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{c110a25 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
D/SecWifiDisplayUtil(11028): Metadata value : SecSettings2
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :org.jtb.alogcat.PrefsActivity
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :org.jtb.alogcat.PrefsActivity
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
I/Timeline(11028): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@f42eaee time:83681389
V/ActivityThread(11028): updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{136c71d token=android.os.BinderProxy@da97a14 {org.jtb.alogcat/org.jtb.alogcat.LogActivity}} show : false
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processKey 0
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processKey 1
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #1 mView = android.widget.LinearLayout{cf3a67f V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
I/Timeline(11028): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@da97a14 time:83702515
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #3 mView = null
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #3 mView = null
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :org.jtb.alogcat.LogActivity
D/AbsListView(11028): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #1 mView = android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView{bb5d076 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchOptionsItemSelected :org.jtb.alogcat.LogActivity
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #3 mView = null
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #1 mView = android.widget.LinearLayout{63eb749 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
E/ViewRootImpl(11028): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #3 mView = null
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :org.jtb.alogcat.LogActivity
D/AbsListView(11028): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #1 mView = android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView{7327f05 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchOptionsItemSelected :org.jtb.alogcat.LogActivity
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #3 mView = null
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #1 mView = android.widget.LinearLayout{2b35b67 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
E/ViewRootImpl(11028): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #3 mView = null
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processKey 0
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processKey 1
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #3 mView = null
W/ResourcesManager(11028): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/org.jtb.alogcat-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in org.jtb.alogcat rsrc of package org.jtb.alogcat
D/AbsListView(11028): Get MotionRecognitionManager
E/MotionRecognitionManager(11028): mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@2e25c2d
E/MotionRecognitionManager(11028): motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@a452562
E/MotionRecognitionManager(11028): motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@a452562
D/Activity(11028): performCreate Call Injection manager
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : org.jtb.alogcat.LogActivity isFragment :false
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{ed435ae I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
D/SecWifiDisplayUtil(11028): Metadata value : SecSettings2
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #1 mView = android.widget.LinearLayout{b4a0f4f V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :org.jtb.alogcat.LogActivity
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :org.jtb.alogcat.LogActivity
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
I/Timeline(11028): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@ca0f6f3 time:83788812
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #3 mView = null
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/InjectionManager(11028): dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :org.jtb.alogcat.LogActivity
D/AbsListView(11028): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): #1 mView = android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView{f736a3f V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
D/ViewRootImpl(11028): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
```

Comment: When debugging the application, I got this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.scottbing.viewshed/com.example.scottbing.viewshed.Viewshed}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: I decided to lower the target API from 24 to 21 and set the minimum API to 15.  This seems to be the magic combination.  The app worked successfully on a Samsung phone and an HP Touchpad.